# Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService - Authorization failed

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core, jwt

### What I have:

I have to working on a web application developed last year not by me. It is composed of a web service back-end and a web application front-end. The back-end is writtenin C# 7, running on the .NET Core 2.1 runtime and using the ASP.NET Core MVC framework. The front-end is a web application written in HTML 5, CSS3, TypeScript and React.

### What I want:

I want to set up a development environment on my PC (using windows 10 as OS).

### What I'v done:

I ran the webpack-dev-server to serve the front-end at http://localhost:8080. Then I ran the back-end using ASP.NET Core in Visual Studio to serve the web service at http://localhost:44311.
Then I reached the login form in the main page at http://localhost:8080.

### The problem:

During the login stage I get the following error (I'm using a valid user and password):

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker:Information: Executed action method MyProject.Controllers.AuthenticationController.Login (MyProject), returned result Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.OkResult in 549.6866ms.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.StatusCodeResult:Information: Executing HttpStatusCodeResult, setting HTTP status code 200
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker:Information: Executed action MyProject.Controllers.AuthenticationController.Login (MyProject) in 620.9287ms
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request finished in 634.4833ms 200 
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request starting HTTP/1.1 OPTIONS http://localhost:44311/Authentication/GetUser  
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.Infrastructure.CorsService:Information: Policy execution successful.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request finished in 2.9016ms 204 
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:44311/Authentication/GetUser application/json 
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.Infrastructure.CorsService:Information: Policy execution successful.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker:Information: Route matched with {action = "GetUser", controller = "Authentication"}. Executing controller action with signature Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.IActionResult GetUser() on controller MyProject.Controllers.AuthenticationController (MyProject).
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService:Information: Authorization failed.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker:Information: Authorization failed for the request at filter 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Authorization.AuthorizeFilter'.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ChallengeResult:Information: Executing ChallengeResult with authentication schemes (Cookies).
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler:Information: AuthenticationScheme: Cookies was challenged.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker:Information: Executed action MyProject.Controllers.AuthenticationController.GetUser (MyProject) in 25.582ms
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request finished in 33.6489ms 302 
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request starting HTTP/1.1 OPTIONS http://localhost:44311/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2FAuthentication%2FGetUser  
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.Infrastructure.CorsService:Information: Policy execution successful.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request finished in 3.2166ms 204 
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:44311/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2FAuthentication%2FGetUser application/json 
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.Infrastructure.CorsService:Information: Policy execution successful.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request finished in 2.7855ms 404
```

---

Here is my **Startup.cs**:

```
    public class Startup
    {
        private readonly IHostingEnvironment _env;
        private readonly IConfiguration _config;

        public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env, IConfiguration config)
        {
            _env = env;
            _config = config;
        }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            JwtConfiguration jwtConfiguration = _config.GetSection("JwtConfiguration").Get<JwtConfiguration>();
            CustomJwtDataFormat jwtDataFormat = CustomJwtDataFormat.Create(jwtConfiguration);

            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
            services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(_config);
            services.AddSingleton<IEmailConfiguration>(_config.GetSection("EmailConfiguration").Get<EmailConfiguration>());
            services.AddSingleton(new LogService(_config.GetSection("AzureLogConfiguration").Get<AzureLogConfiguration>()));
            services.AddSingleton(jwtDataFormat);
            services.AddAuthentication().AddCookie(options => {
                options.Cookie.Name = AuthenticationCookie.COOKIE_NAME;
                options.TicketDataFormat = jwtDataFormat;
            });

            Database.ConnectionString = _config["ConnectionStrings:PostgresDatabase"];
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            ConfigurationBuilder configurationBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
            configurationBuilder.SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath);
            configurationBuilder.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", false, true);

            if (env.IsDevelopment()) {
                app.UseCors(
                    builder => builder
                    .AllowAnyOrigin()
                    .AllowAnyMethod()
                    .AllowAnyHeader()
                    .AllowCredentials()
                );
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                configurationBuilder.AddUserSecrets<Startup>();
            }
            else {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseCookiePolicy();
            app.UseMvc(routes => {
                routes.MapRoute(name: "default", template: "{controller=Site}/{action=Index}");
            });
        }
    }
```

**AuthenticationController.cs** (used to authenticate the user during the login stage):

```
    public class AuthenticationController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IEmailConfiguration _emailConfiguration;
        private readonly LogService _logService;
        private readonly CustomJwtDataFormat _jwt;

        public AuthenticationController(IEmailConfiguration emailConfiguration, LogService logService, CustomJwtDataFormat jwt)
        {
            _emailConfiguration = emailConfiguration;
            _logService = logService;
            _jwt = jwt;
        }

        [AllowAnonymous]
        public IActionResult Login([FromBody] LoginNto loginNto)
        {
            string requestString = string.Format("Username: '{0}', Type: '{1}'", loginNto.Email, loginNto.Type);
            try
            {
                var requestType = ToLoginType(loginNto.Type);
                var userType = UsersMapper.GetUserType(loginNto.Email, loginNto.Pass);
                if (userType != requestType)
                    throw new UnauthorizedAccessException();
                AuthenticationCookie.CreateAndAddToResponse(HttpContext, loginNto.Email, _jwt);
                _logService.RequestResponse("[Authentication/Login]", HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress, null, requestString, Ok().StatusCode);
                return Ok();
            }
            catch (UnauthorizedAccessException e)
            {
                _logService.RequestResponse("[Authentication/Login]", HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress, null, requestString, Unauthorized().StatusCode, e);
                return Unauthorized();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                _logService.RequestResponse("[Authentication/Login]", HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress, null, requestString, 500, e);
                return StatusCode(500);
            }
        }

        [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
        public IActionResult GetUser()
        {
            try
            {
                User user = UsersMapper.Get(AuthenticationCookie.GetAuthenticatedUserEmail(HttpContext, _jwt));
                _logService.RequestResponse("[Authentication/GetUser]", HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress, AuthenticationCookie.GetAuthenticatedUserEmail(HttpContext, _jwt), null, Ok().StatusCode);
                return Ok(Json(user.ForNet()));
            }
            catch (UnauthorizedAccessException e)
            {
                _logService.RequestResponse("[Authentication/GetUser]", HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress, AuthenticationCookie.GetAuthenticatedUserEmail(HttpContext, _jwt), null, Unauthorized().StatusCode, e);
                return Unauthorized();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                _logService.RequestResponse("[Authentication/GetUser]", HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress, AuthenticationCookie.GetAuthenticatedUserEmail(HttpContext, _jwt), null, 500, e);
                return StatusCode(500);
            }
        }
    }
```

**AuthenticationCookie.cs** (used to manage the JWT cookie... I think...):

```
    public class AuthenticationCookie
    {
        public const string COOKIE_NAME = "authentication_cookie";

        public static void CreateAndAddToResponse(HttpContext httpContext, string email, CustomJwtDataFormat jwtDataFormat) {
            httpContext.Response.Cookies.Append(COOKIE_NAME, jwtDataFormat.GenerateToken(email));
        }

        public static string GetAuthenticatedUserEmail(HttpContext httpContext, CustomJwtDataFormat jwt) {
            var tokenValue = httpContext.Request.Cookies[COOKIE_NAME];
            var authenticationTicket = jwt.Unprotect(tokenValue);
            return authenticationTicket.Principal.Claims.First().Value;
        }

        public static void Delete(HttpContext httpContext) {
            httpContext.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        }
    }
```

Comment: When do you get this error while starting the Web Service?

Comment: Could you please include the code of `Startup.cs`? What's the `/Account/Login`? Is there a `AccountController` and a `Login` Action ? Or are you using the default `Identity`?

Comment: I modified the question by integrating the codes of **Startup.cs** and **AuthenticationController.cs** (this is my access controller). The problem occours during the Login stage (I'm using a valid user).

Answer (score 5):

### The Reason

The root reason is that you didn't add a `UseAuthentication()` before `UseMvc()` :

```
    app.UseAuthentication();     // MUST Add this line before UseMvc()
    app.UseMvc(routes => {...});
```

As a result, ASP.NET Core won't create a User Principal for user even he has already signed in. And then you got a message of :

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService:Information: **Authorization failed.**
>
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker:Information: Authorization failed for the request at filter 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Authorization.AuthorizeFilter'.
>
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ChallengeResult:Information: Executing **ChallengeResult** with authentication schemes (Cookies).

Since you didn't configure the Login Path for cookie:

```
services.AddAuthentication().AddCookie(options => {
    options.Cookie.Name = AuthenticationCookie.COOKIE_NAME;
    options.TicketDataFormat = jwtDataFormat;
});
```

So it use the default one, i.e., `/Account/Login`. But you didn't have such a `AccountController` and `Login` action method, you get a response of 404:

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:44311**/Account/Login**?ReturnUrl=%2FAuthentication%2FGetUser application/json
>
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.Infrastructure.CorsService:Information: Policy execution successful.
>
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request finished in 2.7855ms **404**

### How to fix

1. add a `UseAuthentication()` before `UseMvc()` :

   ```
   app.UseAuthentication();  // MUST add this line before UseMvc()
   app.UseMvc(routes => {...});
   ```
2. Create a Controller/View for user to login in if you don't have one. And then tell ASP.NET Core how to redirect user in Startup:

   ```
   services.AddAuthentication().AddCookie(options => {
       options.Cookie.Name = AuthenticationCookie.COOKIE_NAME;
       options.TicketDataFormat = jwtDataFormat;
       options.LoginPath= "/the-path-to-login-in";  // change this line
   });
   ```

---

**[Edit]**

1. Your `Login([FromBody] LoginNto loginNto)` method accepts a `HttpGet` request, but expecting to get a body. HTTP Get has no body at all. You need change it to `HttpPost`:

   ```
   [HttpPost]
   [AllowAnonymous]
   public async Task<IActionResult> Login([FromBody] LoginNto loginNto)
   {
       ...
   }
   ```
2. The way signing in the user seems not correct. Change your Login() method to sends a standard cookie as below:

   ```
   [HttpPost]
   [AllowAnonymous]
   public async Task<IActionResult> Login([FromBody] LoginNto loginNto)
   {
       string requestString = string.Format("Username: '{0}', Type: '{1}'", loginNto.Email, loginNto.Type);
       try
       {
           ...
           if (userType != requestType)
               throw new UnauthorizedAccessException();
           //AuthenticationCookie.CreateAndAddToResponse(HttpContext, loginNto.Email, _jwt);
           await SignInAsync(loginNto.Email, _jwt);
           ...           
           return Ok();
       }
       ...

   }
   async Task SignInAsync(string email, CustomJwtDataFormat jwtDataFormat){
       var schemeName = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
       var claims = new List<Claim>(){
           new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier,  email),
           new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name,  email),
           new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email,  email),
           // ... other claims according to the jwtDataFormat
       };
       var id = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, schemeName);
       var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(id);
       // send credential cookie using the standard 
       await HttpContext.SignInAsync(schemeName,principal);
   }
   ```
3. And the GetUser can also be simplified:

   ```
   [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
   public IActionResult GetUser()
   {
       var email = HttpContext.User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Email);
       User user = UsersMapper.Get(AuthenticationCookie.GetAuthenticatedUserEmail(HttpContext, _jwt));
       _logService.RequestResponse("[Authentication/GetUser]", HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress, AuthenticationCookie.GetAuthenticatedUserEmail(HttpContext, _jwt), null, Ok().StatusCode);        
       var payload= new {
           Email = email,
           // ... other claims that're kept in cookie
       };
       // return Ok(Json(user.ForNet()));
       return Json(payload);
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried to implement it but it doesn't work. I'm not a .NET expert but I seem to have understood that during login the platform performs two operations: first authenticates the user (AuthenticationController.Login) and then collects all the information (AuthenticationController.GetUser). This operation requires the authorization that occurs through the verification of a JWT cookie (I added the AuthenticationCookie.cs). I believe that the Login method is responsible for creating this cookie but, from the attempts made by me, I don't think it is saved in my browser.

Comment: @El_Merendero 1. When you said "tried...it but it doesn't work", I suppose you still get Authentication Failed, is that right? I found that the authentication might be a problem yesterday. But since your original post was asking about "Request finished in 404", I didn't talk much about that.

Comment: @El_Merendero  (too long to post in a single comment) 2. According to my experience, the new question is because you're sending a `cookie: JWT_FORMAT` as the credentials when signing in the user. That's not the standard Cookie Authentication scheme. (But since you didn't provide the `JwtDataFormat`, I'm not totally sure about that). I don't know why you send a JWT as a cookie credential. IMO, it's not necessary. I would suggest you should use the default Cookie Authentication Scheme to send cookie. If you prefer JWT, then use it. Don't mix up JWT with cookie like `Cookie: {JWT}`.

Comment: @El_Merendero please see my Edits for how to update.